# Is there a term to describe how close a system is to being autonomous?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, terminology, dynamical-systems

A dynamical system is either autonomous or not. I would like to know if there is a term to describes the how close a system is to being a autonomous, and if there are standard ways to measure this.

For instance, for a system $\dot{\mathbf{x}} = f(\mathbf{x}) + g(t)$, one could compare the value of $f$ and $g$ over the state space. Or describe how predictable trajectories when the state vector is known but not the forcing term.

Comment: I am not sure that it is what you are asking for, but there is a somewhat developed theory for *asymptotically autonomous equations*, you can google this term.

Comment: The system $\dot{x} = f(x) + \epsilon g(x, t,\epsilon)$ is called a *perturbed autonomous system* (see e.g. Loud, Periodic Solutions of a Perturbed Autonomous Systems, 1959). Typically the interest is studying convergence properties as $\epsilon \to 0$.